# Unable to add a chart to my vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apexcharts

I have a vue.js 2.0 app, and i need to publish the first apex chart example :https://apexcharts.com/docs/vue-charts/

For now, my app is not using the IMPORT syntax and working well . **I'm not using Babel or WebPack.**

This is my router :

```
const routes = [
     { path: "/home", component: Home }
];
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for `routes: routes`
});

const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount("#app");
```

This is my Home component :

```
const Home = {
  data: function() {
    return {
      count: 0
    };
  },
  template:
    `<div>Lots of informations</div> <span>I need to place the chart there</span>`
};
```

If you look at the ApexChart 1st example, i have to use IMPORT and the template balise :

1. Import doesnt work ( error) :

   SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

   [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
2. I can't place a template inside another template .

how could I do ?

Where can I place this code ?

```
<template>
<div>
  <apexchart width="500" type="bar" :options="options" :series="series"></apexchart>
</div>
</template>
```

I am loading Apexcharts in index.html like this :

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts" type="module"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-apexcharts" type="module"></script>
```

***EDIT 2 :***

This is my updated component :

```
const Home = {
  data: function() {
    return {
      options: {
        chart: {
          id: 'vuechart-example'
        },
        xaxis: {
          categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998]
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'series-1',
        data: [30, 40, 45, 50, 49, 60, 70, 91]
      }]
    }
  },
  template:
    '<div><apexchart width="500" type="bar" :options="options" :series="series"></apexchart></div>'
};
```

I'm still getting the following errors :

```
**SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module**

[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <apexchart> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <Anonymous>
       <Root>
```

I'm trying to import like this inside of INDEX.HTML :

```
<script>
import VueApexCharts from 'vue-apexcharts'
Vue.component('apexchart', VueApexCharts)
</script>
```

Do i have to use Babel or something, for import to work ?

Comment: What does your html look like? You should be able to put somerthing like `<apex-chart></apex-chart>` in your home component.

Comment: Thanks, my html are literal templates strings written inside of the JS file ...

Comment: [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <apexchart> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the chart component inside of your homecomponent.

```
import VueApexCharts from 'vue-apexcharts'
Vue.component('apexchart', VueApexCharts)

const Home = {
  data: function() {
    return {
      options: {
        chart: {
          id: 'vuechart-example'
        },
        xaxis: {
          categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998]
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'series-1',
        data: [30, 40, 45, 50, 49, 60, 70, 91]
      }]
    }
  },
  template:
    '<div><apexchart width="500" type="bar" :options="options" :series="series"></apexchart></div>'
};
```

Comment: Thanks, tried to copy this insert inside of template,  but iim getting 2 errors :

Comment: SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Comment: [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <apexchart> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Comment: Post your entire `HomeComponent` in your question.

Comment: Move the import to your home component.

Comment: Inside of the template ?

Comment: Unfortunatly, im still getting this error : SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Comment: If that's the case, then I would copy their sandbox links to a tee and go from there.

Comment: It seems like i have to use Babel or Webpack

Comment: How did you create your project? With the Vue CLI?

Comment: From this green example :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442598/can-we-make-vue-js-application-without-vue-extension-component-and-webpack

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use Babel and some sort of bundler (like webpack) to transpile import statements.

Vanilla JS in the browser doesn't support modules yet.

That, or the component you're using needs to have exposed a browser/CDN version that will define and bootstrap the component globally

Comment: How does he get Vue warnings if he isn't using a bundler?

Comment: Oh, that's a good point. The `INDEX.HTML` bit lead me to believe the `<script>` tag with the `import` statement was not being run through webpack (which it might not be)

Comment: OK, but this guy seems to make it work without Web pack ; https://medium.com/@steveolensky/create-a-spa-vuejs-application-without-node-webpack-or-any-other-build-process-using-vue-router-b9bf8e36e958

Comment: He's using browser/CDN `<script>` tags to import the components.

You're attempting to use module loading without webpack.

Comment: e.g., he uses a `<v-toolbar>` component; this only works because he loaded it via this `<script>` tag: `<script src='./pages/components/toolbar.vue.js'></script>`

Comment: Right now it looks like you're doing both. Just remove the import statement and apex charts should work fine without bundling.

Comment: Added type="module" to the <script> tag, still not working with or without the  IMPORT STATEMENT . It is like i'm missing a part of the syntax to import the module from index.html

Comment: Well, what happens when you completely remove that `<script>` tag with the import statement?

Comment: Yes i've mooved it after new Vue(...) but it is still not working.

Comment: No, you need to completely remove the `import` statement. You do not need to `import` anything if you're using `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-apexcharts"></script>`

Comment: Ah ok, thanks a lot thats what i was wondering ... but I still leave Vue.component('apexchart', VueApexCharts);
Vue.use(apexchart); and it doesnt work either . If I remove all, this is the following : [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <apexchart> - did you register the component correctly?